# Getting error when trying to order by up votes (act_as_votable gem)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So I have the voting working perfectly fine. But when I try to order my posts by most up votes I get this error saying statement invalid in Post Index.

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D8MzU.png)

This is my post controller

```
def index
 @posts = Post.all.order(:cached_votes_up => :desc)
end
```

I have added the Cached votes to posts table migration as well here is the first half of it

```
class AddCachedVotesToPosts < ActiveRecord::Migration
 def self.up
  add_column :posts, :cached_votes_total, :integer, :default => 0
  add_column :posts, :cached_votes_score, :integer, :default => 0
  add_column :posts, :cached_votes_up, :integer, :default => 0
  add_column :posts, :cached_votes_down, :integer, :default => 0
  add_column :posts, :cached_weighted_score, :integer, :default => 0
  add_column :posts, :cached_weighted_total, :integer, :default => 0
  add_column :posts, :cached_weighted_average, :float, :default => 0.0
  add_index  :posts, :cached_votes_total
  add_index  :posts, :cached_votes_score
  add_index  :posts, :cached_votes_up
  add_index  :posts, :cached_votes_down
  add_index  :posts, :cached_weighted_score
  add_index  :posts, :cached_weighted_total
  add_index  :posts, :cached_weighted_average
```

If anymore code will help I will gladly post it

Posts table

```
create_table "posts", force: :cascade do |t|
t.string   "description"
t.datetime "created_at",         null: false
t.datetime "updated_at",         null: false
t.integer  "user_id"
t.string   "image_file_name"
t.string   "image_content_type"
t.integer  "image_file_size"
t.datetime "image_updated_at"
end
```

Comment: Can i see your `posts` table from the schema file.

Comment: @M.Karim I hope that was the table you were asking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cached_votes_up` column not added to your database yet. Please run this command,

```
rake db:migrate:reset
```

It will reset your database migrations and all new columns will be added. It should solve your problem.

**note:** all your database records will be removed by using this command.

Comment: Welcome. Always run `rake db:migrate` after you add any new migration.

Comment: Ya I did. I ran it a few times to make sure. I don't know why it didn't go threw. Next time I know I am having a migration problem I will remember to try rake db:migrate:reset

Comment: I think you edit your previous migrations, thats why. You shouldn't edit your previous migration rather add new migrations each time you want to change anything

Comment: I think that was the issue. I didn't edit any previous migrations. But when I added the AddCachedVotesToPosts migrations it was empty, so I put in the self.up and self.down columns that were on the github page. I ran db:migrate after that and still nothing. But now I will definitely remember this if I ever have to add stuff to a migration like this. Thank you again. You were a ton of help